# UniswapV3 Fork with updated POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH

Tags: contract-deployment, uniswap, hardhat-deploy, uniswapv3, deployed-bytecode

I am trying to modify the the standard tests for UniswapV3 staker, which is deployed with different POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH, but so far the tests that are failing resulting the following Error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Uniswap3V3Staker::stakeToken: token pool is not the incentive pool
```

Here is one of the test files

```
import { constants, BigNumberish, Wallet } from 'ethers'
import { LoadFixtureFunction } from '../types'
import { ethers } from 'hardhat'
import { uniswapFixture, mintPosition, UniswapFixtureType } from '../shared/fixtures'
import {
  expect,
  getMaxTick,
  getMinTick,
  FeeAmount,
  TICK_SPACINGS,
  blockTimestamp,
  BN,
  BNe18,
  snapshotGasCost,
  ActorFixture,
  makeTimestamps,
  maxGas,
} from '../shared'
import { createFixtureLoader, provider } from '../shared/provider'
import { HelperCommands, ERC20Helper, incentiveResultToStakeAdapter } from '../helpers'

import { ContractParams } from '../../types/contractParams'
import { createTimeMachine } from '../shared/time'
import { HelperTypes } from '../helpers/types'

let loadFixture: LoadFixtureFunction

describe('unit/Deposits', () => {
  const actors = new ActorFixture(provider.getWallets(), provider)
  const lpUser0 = actors.lpUser0()
  const amountDesired = BNe18(10)
  const totalReward = BNe18(100)
  const erc20Helper = new ERC20Helper()
  const Time = createTimeMachine(provider)
  let helpers: HelperCommands
  let context: UniswapFixtureType

  before('loader', async () => {
    loadFixture = createFixtureLoader(provider.getWallets(), provider)
  })

  beforeEach('create fixture loader', async () => {
    context = await loadFixture(uniswapFixture)
    helpers = HelperCommands.fromTestContext(context, actors, provider)
  })

  let tokenId: string

  const SAFE_TRANSFER_FROM_SIGNATURE = 'safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)'
  const INCENTIVE_KEY_ABI =
    'tuple(address rewardToken, address pool, uint256 startTime, uint256 endTime, address refundee)'

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await erc20Helper.ensureBalancesAndApprovals(
      lpUser0,
      [context.token0, context.token1],
      amountDesired,
      context.nft.address
    )

    tokenId = await mintPosition(context.nft.connect(lpUser0), {
      token0: context.token0.address,
      token1: context.token1.address,
      fee: FeeAmount.MEDIUM,
      tickLower: getMinTick(TICK_SPACINGS[FeeAmount.MEDIUM]),
      tickUpper: getMaxTick(TICK_SPACINGS[FeeAmount.MEDIUM]),
      recipient: lpUser0.address,
      amount0Desired: amountDesired,
      amount1Desired: amountDesired,
      amount0Min: 0,
      amount1Min: 0,
      deadline: (await blockTimestamp()) + 1000,
    })
  })

  describe('nft#safeTransferFrom', () => {
    /**
     * We're ultimately checking these variables, so subject calls with calldata (from actor)
     * and returns those three objects. */
    let subject: (calldata: string, actor?: Wallet) => Promise<void>

    let createIncentiveResult: HelperTypes.CreateIncentive.Result

    beforeEach('setup', async () => {
      const { startTime } = makeTimestamps(await blockTimestamp())

      createIncentiveResult = await helpers.createIncentiveFlow({
        rewardToken: context.rewardToken,
        poolAddress: context.poolObj.address,
        startTime,
        totalReward,
      })

      await Time.setAndMine(startTime + 1)

      // Make sure we're starting from a clean slate
      const depositBefore = await context.staker.deposits(tokenId)
      expect(depositBefore.owner).to.eq(constants.AddressZero)
      expect(depositBefore.numberOfStakes).to.eq(0)

      subject = async (data: string, actor: Wallet = lpUser0) => {
        await context.nft
          .connect(actor)
          [SAFE_TRANSFER_FROM_SIGNATURE](actor.address, context.staker.address, tokenId, data, {
            ...maxGas,
            from: actor.address,
          })
      }
    })

    it.only('allows depositing and staking for a single incentive', async () => {
      const data = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        [INCENTIVE_KEY_ABI],
        [incentiveResultToStakeAdapter(createIncentiveResult)]
      )
      console.log('context', context.poolObj.address)

      await subject(data, lpUser0)
      // const { deposit, incentive, stake } = await getTokenInfo(tokenId)
      // expect(deposit.owner).to.eq(lpUser0.address)
      // expect(deposit.numberOfStakes).to.eq(BN('1'))
      // expect(incentive.numberOfStakes).to.eq(BN('1'))
      // expect(stake.secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128).not.to.eq(BN('0'))
    })

    
  })
})
```

Here are the fixtures

```
import { Fixture } from 'ethereum-waffle'
import { constants } from 'ethers'
import { ethers, waffle } from 'hardhat'

import { defaultAbiCoder } from '@ethersproject/abi'
import { getCreate2Address } from '@ethersproject/address'
import { keccak256 } from '@ethersproject/solidity'

import UniswapV3Pool from '@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json'
import UniswapV3FactoryJson from '@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json'
import NFTDescriptorJson from '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol/NFTDescriptor.json'
import NonfungiblePositionManagerJson from '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json'
import NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor from '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.sol/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.json'
import SwapRouter from '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/SwapRouter.sol/SwapRouter.json'
import WETH9 from './external/WETH9.json'
import { linkLibraries } from './linkLibraries'
import { ISwapRouter } from '../../types/ISwapRouter'
import { IWETH9 } from '../../types/IWETH9'
import {
  Lif3V3Staker,
  TestERC20,
  INonfungiblePositionManager,
  IUniswapV3Factory,
  IUniswapV3Pool,
  TestIncentiveId,
} from '../../typechain'
import { NFTDescriptor } from '../../types/NFTDescriptor'
import { FeeAmount, BigNumber, encodePriceSqrt, MAX_GAS_LIMIT } from '../shared'
import { ActorFixture } from './actors'

type WETH9Fixture = { weth9: IWETH9 }

export const wethFixture: Fixture<WETH9Fixture> = async ([wallet]) => {
  const weth9 = (await waffle.deployContract(wallet, {
    bytecode: WETH9.bytecode,
    abi: WETH9.abi,
  })) as IWETH9

  return { weth9 }
}

const v3CoreFactoryFixture: Fixture<IUniswapV3Factory> = async ([wallet]) => {
  return ((await waffle.deployContract(wallet, {
    bytecode: UniswapV3FactoryJson.bytecode,
    abi: UniswapV3FactoryJson.abi,
  })) as unknown) as IUniswapV3Factory
}

export const v3RouterFixture: Fixture<{
  weth9: IWETH9
  factory: IUniswapV3Factory
  router: ISwapRouter
}> = async ([wallet], provider) => {
  const { weth9 } = await wethFixture([wallet], provider)
  const factory = await v3CoreFactoryFixture([wallet], provider)
  const router = ((await waffle.deployContract(
    wallet,
    {
      bytecode: SwapRouter.bytecode,
      abi: SwapRouter.abi,
    },
    [factory.address, weth9.address]
  )) as unknown) as ISwapRouter

  return { factory, weth9, router }
}


const nftDescriptorLibraryFixture: Fixture<NFTDescriptor> = async ([wallet]) => {
  return (await waffle.deployContract(wallet, {
    bytecode: NFTDescriptorJson.bytecode,
    abi: NFTDescriptorJson.abi,
  })) as NFTDescriptor
}

type UniswapFactoryFixture = {
  weth9: IWETH9
  factory: IUniswapV3Factory
  router: ISwapRouter
  nft: INonfungiblePositionManager
  tokens: [TestERC20, TestERC20, TestERC20]
}

// bytes32 internal constant POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH = 0x88ea7049e70592b519fc358b446165d4dbedb71ff7c3749add6dc16731e6cd5a; //0x1b119fef4adc071cd75f23ea764c138d56e57db5050bddcb7708a3b47790d447;
const POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH = "0x1b119fef4adc071cd75f23ea764c138d56e57db5050bddcb7708a3b47790d447"
export function computePoolAddress({
  factoryAddress,
  tokenA,
  tokenB,
  fee,
}: {
  factoryAddress: string
  tokenA: TestERC20
  tokenB: TestERC20
  fee: FeeAmount
}): string {
  const [token0, token1] = [tokenA, tokenB] // does safety checks
  return getCreate2Address(
    factoryAddress,
    keccak256(
      ['bytes'],
      [defaultAbiCoder.encode(['address', 'address', 'uint24'], [token0.address, token1.address, fee])]
    ),
    POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
  )
}

export const uniswapFactoryFixture: Fixture<UniswapFactoryFixture> = async (wallets, provider) => {
  const { weth9, factory, router } = await v3RouterFixture(wallets, provider)
  const tokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('TestERC20')
  const tokens = (await Promise.all([
    tokenFactory.deploy(constants.MaxUint256.div(2)), // do not use maxu256 to avoid overflowing
    tokenFactory.deploy(constants.MaxUint256.div(2)),
    tokenFactory.deploy(constants.MaxUint256.div(2)),
  ])) as [TestERC20, TestERC20, TestERC20]

  const nftDescriptorLibrary = await nftDescriptorLibraryFixture(wallets, provider)

  const linkedBytecode = linkLibraries(
    {
      bytecode: NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.bytecode,
      linkReferences: {
        'NFTDescriptor.sol': {
          NFTDescriptor: [
            {
              length: 20,
              start: 1261,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      NFTDescriptor: nftDescriptorLibrary.address,
    }
  )

  const positionDescriptor = await waffle.deployContract(
    wallets[0],
    {
      bytecode: linkedBytecode,
      abi: NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.abi,
    },
    [tokens[0].address]
  )

  const nftFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(
    NonfungiblePositionManagerJson.abi,
    NonfungiblePositionManagerJson.bytecode,
    wallets[0]
  )
  const nft = (await nftFactory.deploy(
    factory.address,
    weth9.address,
    positionDescriptor.address
  )) as INonfungiblePositionManager

  tokens.sort((a, b) => (a.address.toLowerCase() < b.address.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1))

  return {
    weth9,
    factory,
    router,
    tokens,
    nft,
  }
}

export const mintPosition = async (
  nft: INonfungiblePositionManager,
  mintParams: {
    token0: string
    token1: string
    fee: FeeAmount
    tickLower: number
    tickUpper: number
    recipient: string
    amount0Desired: any
    amount1Desired: any
    amount0Min: number
    amount1Min: number
    deadline: number
  }
): Promise<string> => {
  const transferFilter = nft.filters.Transfer(null, null, null)
  const transferTopic = nft.interface.getEventTopic('Transfer')

  let tokenId: BigNumber | undefined

  const receipt = await (
    await nft.mint(
      {
        token0: mintParams.token0,
        token1: mintParams.token1,
        fee: mintParams.fee,
        tickLower: mintParams.tickLower,
        tickUpper: mintParams.tickUpper,
        recipient: mintParams.recipient,
        amount0Desired: mintParams.amount0Desired,
        amount1Desired: mintParams.amount1Desired,
        amount0Min: mintParams.amount0Min,
        amount1Min: mintParams.amount1Min,
        deadline: mintParams.deadline,
      },
      {
        gasLimit: MAX_GAS_LIMIT,
      }
    )
  ).wait()

  for (let i = 0; i < receipt.logs.length; i++) {
    const log = receipt.logs[i]
    if (log.address === nft.address && log.topics.includes(transferTopic)) {
      // for some reason log.data is 0x so this hack just re-fetches it
      const events = await nft.queryFilter(transferFilter, log.blockHash)
      if (events.length === 1) {
        tokenId = events[0].args?.tokenId
      }
      break
    }
  }

  if (tokenId === undefined) {
    throw 'could not find tokenId after mint'
  } else {
    return tokenId.toString()
  }
}

export type UniswapFixtureType = {
  factory: IUniswapV3Factory
  fee: FeeAmount
  nft: INonfungiblePositionManager
  pool01: string
  pool12: string
  poolObj: IUniswapV3Pool
  poolAddress: string
  router: ISwapRouter
  staker: Lif3V3Staker
  testIncentiveId: TestIncentiveId
  tokens: [TestERC20, TestERC20, TestERC20]
  token0: TestERC20
  token1: TestERC20
  rewardToken: TestERC20
}
export const uniswapFixture: Fixture<UniswapFixtureType> = async (wallets, provider) => {
  const { tokens, nft, factory, router } = await uniswapFactoryFixture(wallets, provider)
  const signer = new ActorFixture(wallets, provider).stakerDeployer()
  const stakerFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Lif3V3Staker', signer)
  const staker = (await stakerFactory.deploy(factory.address, nft.address, 2 ** 32, 2 ** 32)) as Lif3V3Staker

  const testIncentiveIdFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('TestIncentiveId', signer)
  const testIncentiveId = (await testIncentiveIdFactory.deploy()) as TestIncentiveId

  for (const token of tokens) {
    await token.approve(nft.address, constants.MaxUint256)
  }

  const fee = FeeAmount.MEDIUM
  await nft.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(tokens[0].address, tokens[1].address, fee, encodePriceSqrt(1, 1))

  await nft.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(tokens[1].address, tokens[2].address, fee, encodePriceSqrt(1, 1))

  const pool01 = await factory.getPool(tokens[0].address, tokens[1].address, fee)

  const pool12 = await factory.getPool(tokens[1].address, tokens[2].address, fee)

  const poolObj = poolFactory.attach(pool01) as IUniswapV3Pool

  return {
    nft,
    router,
    tokens,
    staker,
    testIncentiveId,
    factory,
    pool01,
    pool12,
    fee,
    poolObj,
    poolAddress: computePoolAddress({ factoryAddress: factory.address, tokenA: tokens[0], tokenB: tokens[1], fee }),
    token0: tokens[0],
    token1: tokens[1],
    rewardToken: tokens[2],
  }
}

export const poolFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(UniswapV3Pool.abi, UniswapV3Pool.bytecode)
```

And here is the code of the UniswapStaker contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity =0.7.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import './interfaces/IUniswapV3Staker.sol';
import './libraries/IncentiveId.sol';
import './libraries/RewardMath.sol';
import './libraries/NFTPositionInfo.sol';
import './libraries/TransferHelperExtended.sol';

import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IERC20Minimal.sol';

import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/base/Multicall.sol';

/// @title Uniswap V3 canonical staking interface
contract UniswapV3Staker is IUniswapV3Staker, Multicall {
    /// @notice Represents a staking incentive
    struct Incentive {
        uint256 totalRewardUnclaimed;
        uint160 totalSecondsClaimedX128;
        uint96 numberOfStakes;
    }

    /// @notice Represents the deposit of a liquidity NFT
    struct Deposit {
        address owner;
        uint48 numberOfStakes;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
    }

    /// @notice Represents a staked liquidity NFT
    struct Stake {
        uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128;
        uint96 liquidityNoOverflow;
        uint128 liquidityIfOverflow;
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    IUniswapV3Factory public immutable override factory;
    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    INonfungiblePositionManager public immutable override nonfungiblePositionManager;

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    uint256 public immutable override maxIncentiveStartLeadTime;
    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    uint256 public immutable override maxIncentiveDuration;

    /// @dev bytes32 refers to the return value of IncentiveId.compute
    mapping(bytes32 => Incentive) public override incentives;

    /// @dev deposits[tokenId] => Deposit
    mapping(uint256 => Deposit) public override deposits;

    /// @dev stakes[tokenId][incentiveHash] => Stake
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(bytes32 => Stake)) private _stakes;

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function stakes(uint256 tokenId, bytes32 incentiveId)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128, uint128 liquidity)
    {
        Stake storage stake = _stakes[tokenId][incentiveId];
        secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128 = stake.secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128;
        liquidity = stake.liquidityNoOverflow;
        if (liquidity == type(uint96).max) {
            liquidity = stake.liquidityIfOverflow;
        }
    }

    /// @dev rewards[rewardToken][owner] => uint256
    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    mapping(IERC20Minimal => mapping(address => uint256)) public override rewards;

    /// @param _factory the Uniswap V3 factory
    /// @param _nonfungiblePositionManager the NFT position manager contract address
    /// @param _maxIncentiveStartLeadTime the max duration of an incentive in seconds
    /// @param _maxIncentiveDuration the max amount of seconds into the future the incentive startTime can be set
    constructor(
        IUniswapV3Factory _factory,
        INonfungiblePositionManager _nonfungiblePositionManager,
        uint256 _maxIncentiveStartLeadTime,
        uint256 _maxIncentiveDuration
    ) {
        factory = _factory;
        nonfungiblePositionManager = _nonfungiblePositionManager;
        maxIncentiveStartLeadTime = _maxIncentiveStartLeadTime;
        maxIncentiveDuration = _maxIncentiveDuration;
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function createIncentive(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 reward) external override {
        require(reward > 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::createIncentive: reward must be positive');
        require(
            block.timestamp <= key.startTime,
            'UniswapV3Staker::createIncentive: start time must be now or in the future'
        );
        require(
            key.startTime - block.timestamp <= maxIncentiveStartLeadTime,
            'UniswapV3Staker::createIncentive: start time too far into future'
        );
        require(key.startTime < key.endTime, 'UniswapV3Staker::createIncentive: start time must be before end time');
        require(
            key.endTime - key.startTime <= maxIncentiveDuration,
            'UniswapV3Staker::createIncentive: incentive duration is too long'
        );

        bytes32 incentiveId = IncentiveId.compute(key);

        incentives[incentiveId].totalRewardUnclaimed += reward;

        TransferHelperExtended.safeTransferFrom(address(key.rewardToken), msg.sender, address(this), reward);

        emit IncentiveCreated(key.rewardToken, key.pool, key.startTime, key.endTime, key.refundee, reward);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function endIncentive(IncentiveKey memory key) external override returns (uint256 refund) {
        require(block.timestamp >= key.endTime, 'UniswapV3Staker::endIncentive: cannot end incentive before end time');

        bytes32 incentiveId = IncentiveId.compute(key);
        Incentive storage incentive = incentives[incentiveId];

        refund = incentive.totalRewardUnclaimed;

        require(refund > 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::endIncentive: no refund available');
        require(
            incentive.numberOfStakes == 0,
            'UniswapV3Staker::endIncentive: cannot end incentive while deposits are staked'
        );

        // issue the refund
        incentive.totalRewardUnclaimed = 0;
        TransferHelperExtended.safeTransfer(address(key.rewardToken), key.refundee, refund);

        // note we never clear totalSecondsClaimedX128

        emit IncentiveEnded(incentiveId, refund);
    }

    /// @notice Upon receiving a Uniswap V3 ERC721, creates the token deposit setting owner to `from`. Also stakes token
    /// in one or more incentives if properly formatted `data` has a length > 0.
    /// @inheritdoc IERC721Receiver
    function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override returns (bytes4) {
        require(
            msg.sender == address(nonfungiblePositionManager),
            'UniswapV3Staker::onERC721Received: not a univ3 nft'
        );

        (, , , , , int24 tickLower, int24 tickUpper, , , , , ) = nonfungiblePositionManager.positions(tokenId);

        deposits[tokenId] = Deposit({owner: from, numberOfStakes: 0, tickLower: tickLower, tickUpper: tickUpper});
        emit DepositTransferred(tokenId, address(0), from);

        if (data.length > 0) {
            if (data.length == 160) {
                _stakeToken(abi.decode(data, (IncentiveKey)), tokenId);
            } else {
                IncentiveKey[] memory keys = abi.decode(data, (IncentiveKey[]));
                for (uint256 i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    _stakeToken(keys[i], tokenId);
                }
            }
        }
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function transferDeposit(uint256 tokenId, address to) external override {
        require(to != address(0), 'UniswapV3Staker::transferDeposit: invalid transfer recipient');
        address owner = deposits[tokenId].owner;
        require(owner == msg.sender, 'UniswapV3Staker::transferDeposit: can only be called by deposit owner');
        deposits[tokenId].owner = to;
        emit DepositTransferred(tokenId, owner, to);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function withdrawToken(
        uint256 tokenId,
        address to,
        bytes memory data
    ) external override {
        require(to != address(this), 'UniswapV3Staker::withdrawToken: cannot withdraw to staker');
        Deposit memory deposit = deposits[tokenId];
        require(deposit.numberOfStakes == 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::withdrawToken: cannot withdraw token while staked');
        require(deposit.owner == msg.sender, 'UniswapV3Staker::withdrawToken: only owner can withdraw token');

        delete deposits[tokenId];
        emit DepositTransferred(tokenId, deposit.owner, address(0));

        nonfungiblePositionManager.safeTransferFrom(address(this), to, tokenId, data);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function stakeToken(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 tokenId) external override {
        require(deposits[tokenId].owner == msg.sender, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: only owner can stake token');

        _stakeToken(key, tokenId);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function unstakeToken(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 tokenId) external override {
        Deposit memory deposit = deposits[tokenId];
        // anyone can call unstakeToken if the block time is after the end time of the incentive
        if (block.timestamp < key.endTime) {
            require(
                deposit.owner == msg.sender,
                'UniswapV3Staker::unstakeToken: only owner can withdraw token before incentive end time'
            );
        }

        bytes32 incentiveId = IncentiveId.compute(key);

        (uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128, uint128 liquidity) = stakes(tokenId, incentiveId);

        require(liquidity != 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::unstakeToken: stake does not exist');

        Incentive storage incentive = incentives[incentiveId];

        deposits[tokenId].numberOfStakes--;
        incentive.numberOfStakes--;

        (, uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128, ) =
            key.pool.snapshotCumulativesInside(deposit.tickLower, deposit.tickUpper);
        (uint256 reward, uint160 secondsInsideX128) =
            RewardMath.computeRewardAmount(
                incentive.totalRewardUnclaimed,
                incentive.totalSecondsClaimedX128,
                key.startTime,
                key.endTime,
                liquidity,
                secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128,
                secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128,
                block.timestamp
            );

        // if this overflows, e.g. after 2^32-1 full liquidity seconds have been claimed,
        // reward rate will fall drastically so it's safe
        incentive.totalSecondsClaimedX128 += secondsInsideX128;
        // reward is never greater than total reward unclaimed
        incentive.totalRewardUnclaimed -= reward;
        // this only overflows if a token has a total supply greater than type(uint256).max
        rewards[key.rewardToken][deposit.owner] += reward;

        Stake storage stake = _stakes[tokenId][incentiveId];
        delete stake.secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128;
        delete stake.liquidityNoOverflow;
        if (liquidity >= type(uint96).max) delete stake.liquidityIfOverflow;
        emit TokenUnstaked(tokenId, incentiveId);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function claimReward(
        IERC20Minimal rewardToken,
        address to,
        uint256 amountRequested
    ) external override returns (uint256 reward) {
        reward = rewards[rewardToken][msg.sender];
        if (amountRequested != 0 && amountRequested < reward) {
            reward = amountRequested;
        }

        rewards[rewardToken][msg.sender] -= reward;
        TransferHelperExtended.safeTransfer(address(rewardToken), to, reward);

        emit RewardClaimed(to, reward);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3Staker
    function getRewardInfo(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 tokenId)
        external
        view
        override
        returns (uint256 reward, uint160 secondsInsideX128)
    {
        bytes32 incentiveId = IncentiveId.compute(key);

        (uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128, uint128 liquidity) = stakes(tokenId, incentiveId);
        require(liquidity > 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::getRewardInfo: stake does not exist');

        Deposit memory deposit = deposits[tokenId];
        Incentive memory incentive = incentives[incentiveId];

        (, uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128, ) =
            key.pool.snapshotCumulativesInside(deposit.tickLower, deposit.tickUpper);

        (reward, secondsInsideX128) = RewardMath.computeRewardAmount(
            incentive.totalRewardUnclaimed,
            incentive.totalSecondsClaimedX128,
            key.startTime,
            key.endTime,
            liquidity,
            secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128,
            secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    /// @dev Stakes a deposited token without doing an ownership check
    function _stakeToken(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 tokenId) private {
        require(block.timestamp >= key.startTime, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: incentive not started');
        require(block.timestamp < key.endTime, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: incentive ended');

        bytes32 incentiveId = IncentiveId.compute(key);

        require(
            incentives[incentiveId].totalRewardUnclaimed > 0,
            'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: non-existent incentive'
        );
        require(
            _stakes[tokenId][incentiveId].liquidityNoOverflow == 0,
            'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: token already staked'
        );

        (IUniswapV3Pool pool, int24 tickLower, int24 tickUpper, uint128 liquidity) =
            NFTPositionInfo.getPositionInfo(factory, nonfungiblePositionManager, tokenId);

        require(pool == key.pool, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: token pool is not the incentive pool');
        require(liquidity > 0, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: cannot stake token with 0 liquidity');

        deposits[tokenId].numberOfStakes++;
        incentives[incentiveId].numberOfStakes++;

        (, uint160 secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128, ) = pool.snapshotCumulativesInside(tickLower, tickUpper);

        if (liquidity >= type(uint96).max) {
            _stakes[tokenId][incentiveId] = Stake({
                secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128: secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128,
                liquidityNoOverflow: type(uint96).max,
                liquidityIfOverflow: liquidity
            });
        } else {
            Stake storage stake = _stakes[tokenId][incentiveId];
            stake.secondsPerLiquidityInsideInitialX128 = secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128;
            stake.liquidityNoOverflow = uint96(liquidity);
        }

        emit TokenStaked(tokenId, incentiveId, liquidity);
    }
}
```

I figured out that the problem comes from the fact that the poolObj from the context is calculated by the default POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH, and so the key.pool(key is parameter passed to _stake() function) and pool (variable calculated with new POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH inside the _stake function) are not equal, thus throwing the corresponding error message from the requirement:

```
 function _stakeToken(IncentiveKey memory key, uint256 tokenId) private {

        (IUniswapV3Pool pool, int24 tickLower, int24 tickUpper, uint128 liquidity) =
            NFTPositionInfo.getPositionInfo(factory, nonfungiblePositionManager, tokenId);

        require(pool == key.pool, 'UniswapV3Staker::stakeToken: token pool is not the incentive pool');

        
    }
```

How can I modify the fixtures, so the poolObj is deployed at the address, computed with the new POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH?
Can provide more details if needed.